# Having trouble booting ubuntu 12.04 desktop from usb in windows 7

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb-drive, iso

I have written the image onto my usb drive. Everything went through, however once i restart my pc, it wont read the disk. Do i need to open safemode to boot? Or should I reformat the drive and rewrite the iso to the stick? I also created a partition on my hard drive for Ubuntu. I formally had ubuntu 10 but i was unable to upgrade it so i removed it. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a live usb boot  make sure you follow [these](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) instructions, or using any other software you like, is extremely difficult to do it manually.

After doing that there is still a pitfall to reach, you have to configure you **BIOS settings** to allow you computer to boot from a **USB drive**, to do this, whe you computer is starting it shows a loading screen from you bios provider, that screen usually has a list of the key bindings, one for **BIOS settings** (*f12*, *spr* or other key) and other for **Boot device options**.

You can press the key associated with **Boot device options** and then select you USB drive or go to **BIOS settings** and look for *boot options* where I'm sure you can find something like boot device order or priority and set you USB drive over your hard drive.

After this is done, hopefully you will be allowed to boot from your USB, also, I think that's a great way to install Ubuntu, way more efficient than using a CD or DVD.